# Деление больших чисел в Go

Tags: golang, biginteger

Учусь программировать на Go, решаю задачки с проекта Эйлер. Есть число 600851475143 к нему надо подобрать наибольший общий делитель, но оно больше чем uint64 в Go и при работе с ним происходит переполнение. Что бы этого избежать я так понял нужно использовать библиотеку math/big. Для примера:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "math/big" 

func main(){
  a := big.NewInt(600851475143) 
  b := big.NewInt(2)
  c := del(a, b)
  fmt.Println("c =", c)
}

func del (a, b *big.Int) *big.Int{
  return a / b
}
```

Почему тут ошибка `invalid operation: a / b (operator / not defined on pointer)`?

Как делить большие числа?

Comment: Ваше число вполне помещается в uint64:

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/oRZr9OBBmdO

Comment: Не "наибольший общий делитель" а "наибольший делитель". Слово "общий" полностью меняет смысл сказанного, лишая задачу смысла.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В го нет перегрузки операторов. Используйте метод [`Div`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int.Div):

```
a := big.NewInt(600851475143)
b := big.NewInt(2)
c := big.NewInt(0).Div(a, b)
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/n45zTFt8SBR.

Comment: Да так работает, но если я b беру здесь в цикл for. Например так получается ошибка. 
    func main(){
   a := big.NewInt(600851475143)
   b := big.NewInt(2) 
   for b< *big.Int(10){  
   c := big.NewInt(0).Div(a, b)
fmt.Println("C=",c)
b++
}
}

Comment: @VitaliusKravtsov Ещё раз. Перегрузки операторов в го нет. Используйте метод [`Cmp`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int.Cmp). В [документации](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int) всё есть.